# How to record pipeline even if sender doesn't send data in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I'm a newbie to gstreamer so i would be appreciated if you could help me.

I'm trying to listen to a pipeline and record frames to a file. 
I have tried the following pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5600 do-timestamp=true ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! clockoverlay ! jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=stream.avi
```

I want to record whole timeline even if the sender doesn't provide any frame data. 
In default, recorder appends the frames when pipeline receive some valid frames. But I want to see some black frames when sender doesn't send data.

Answer (score 1):

I experimented a bit and I don't think you'll be able to do this with a plain `gst-launch` command.  Unfortunately what it would probably involve is to write an application that detects when packets/buffers are not coming in any more, and then modifying the pipeline.  If you want to give it a go I'd suggest the `input-selector` element in something like this:

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc pattern=black ! video/x-raw ! input-selector name=selector ! clockoverlay ! jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=stream.avi`

Then I'd create a method to attach the stream to the input-selector:

`udpsrc port=5600 do-timestamp=true ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 !  rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! identity name=buffer-checker`

To detect no packets coming in, you can listen for the `handoff` signal on the `identity` element, and then remove the stream when it times out and switch over to the black test pattern from the `videotestsrc` by using the `active-pad` property on the `input-selector`.

Using the `videomixer` element *almost* works, but I don't believe it will handle multiple stops and starts of the stream.

Anyway, hope someone else comes up with a better idea.  You could also re-analyze your top level approach and see if there is a way you can work with multiple video clips instead of the one.

Comment: I would say the videomixer would work.. what exactly is it doing upon multiple pauses/stops of stream? what about using identity single-segment?

Comment: Once the stream is attached to videomixer, videomixer seems to expect it to behave and deliver frames.  If frames aren't delivered by one incoming sink it halts the outgoing source.  I'd have to read up on single-segment, it's new to me.